# TFS 2018 Project Folder Permissions

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-security

I am having trouble finding a feature that was in TFS2015.

In TFS2015 i could set folder and file level securty, but i can't find that option in TFS2018. Has this feature moved, or been removed?

TFS2015:

[image: TFS2015]

TFS2018:

[image: TFS2018]

Comment: In the first screenshot you're in a TFVC repository and in the second you're in a Git repository. It's nothing to do with the version of TFS, the security models for TFVC and Git are different.

Comment: @PeroP. Oh... I didn't relize that would change the way security is managed. Thanks! i created a new test project and verified that i can set folder security using TFVC. AWESOME!

Moderators - can this question get closed with Pero P. response as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't due to a difference between versions of TFS, it's due to differences between TFVC and Git.

In the first screenshot (TFS 2015) you are working within a TFVC repository, in the second (TFS 2018) a Git repository.

TFVC and Git have different security models so it's not possible to lock down a specific path in a Git repo like you do in TFVC. With Git repos in TFS you could either:

1. Apply [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?toc=/vsts/git/toc.json&bc=/vsts/git/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=vsts) to a branch
2. Or, if you want to lock down changes to a specific path in a branch is to switch on [branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/branch-policies?view=vsts) and use the [code reviewer policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/branch-policies?view=vsts#automatically-include-code-reviewers) to require a reviewer to approve changes in a specific path of your code base.